# How to implement autodetect user location in react-native

Tags: geolocation, react-native, react-native-ios, google-location-services

I am trying to implement **automatically detect user location** feature in react-native using **geolocation API**  but if the location service is disabled, it doesn't ask user to activate it like it does in various android apps where it asks a user to activate it using google location services and then fetching the user's location.

Can anyone suggest, how can I implement this feature. Also is there any way of doing it for both ios and android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions/) to easily ask for location permission on both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you would just need auto-detect geo location then a better and easiest way is to use `"navigator.geolocation"`. You can get more details about its usage to get location [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) the browser based API.

You don't even need to import as its already inherited by your browser. You can use within class directly:

```
class className extends Component {


  state = {
    initialPosition: 'unknown',
    lastPosition: 'unknown',
 }

   watchID: ? number = null;
   componentDidMount = () => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
         (position) => {
            const initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
            this.setState({ initialPosition });
         },
         (error) => alert(error.message),
         { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
      );
      this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
         const lastPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
         this.setState({ lastPosition });
      });
   }
   componentWillUnmount = () => {
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
   }
}
```